# Oracle ADF - Access bean from another bean

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a tasflow. Inside of that taskflow are two managed beans:

- beanOne (Session scope)
- beanTwo (Request scope)

From beanTwo I need to access a method in beanOne. How can I call a beanOne from beanTwo programmaticly?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Check this: https://mjabr.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/access-an-instance-of-a-managed-bean-from-another-managed-bean/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it. But it is not a good practice.

```
private BeanOne getBeanOne() {
    return (BeanOne)ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope().get("BeanOneName");
}

private void beanOneMethodExecution() {
    getBeanOne().executeSomeMethod();
}
```